# In permission, it always prompt me to enter password

Tags: macos, mac, macbook

everyone!

I have a little problem in permission,
When I'm saving a file or create folder(file)..
the MAC OS prompt me to enter a user password..

How can I fix that - (reset the user permission to default)?

regards to everyone.

Comment: Creating a folder or file...in what location?

Comment: In any path of root (desktop, documents, .... etc)

Answer (score 0):

By default, OSX requires password to change important parts of the filesystem.
Maybe you should state why you are needing to do this.
It is usually not a good idea to turn this feature off unless you really know the filesystem of OSX and even then it could prevent an unintentional malware install or other accident.
You can change permissions in OSX for folders and files by right clicking and unlocking the lock icon and setting the permissions for everyone to read and write.

Comment: It's not important filesystem..

Comment: i.g. create empty folder on desktop, it doesn't require password by default! however, i wanna to reset my mac premession

Comment: check the permissions of the home folder by right clicking and get info.

Comment: its 'rw' for user. and 'r' for everyone and staff.

Comment: try and create a folder in the home folder. Does it ask for permission here?

Comment: i tried to edit ruby file by TextMate, then i saved the file. it required a user pass!